# php imagejpeg() function allways set quality of 96 dpi

Tags: php, image-processing

after uploading an image I place it in a folder using `imagejpeg()`
[documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) says that this function resamples the image to a given quality, depending on third param in the function:

```
imagejpeg($newimg, $path, 80);
```

problem - whatever value I set as quality (50 - 70 - 99 ...) the resulting image is always `96 dpi`

so how to get an image having `72 dpi` ?

Comment: DPI and quality are two totally different things to begin with.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPI and quality are two completely different things.

The **DPI** is a piece of metadata that tells software how to scale the number of pixels in the image into inches. (This is generally only used when printing onto paper and in image editing software such as Photoshop; rendering the image on a website will work in pixels not inches).

The **quality** determines how much compression to use.

---

[The `imageresolution` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php) lets you adjust the DPI metadata.

```
imageresolution($image, 72);
```

[This comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php#78523), on the page you linked to, explains how to adjust the DPI setting manually.

> ```
> <?php
>
>   imagejpeg($image, $file, 75);
>
>   // Change DPI
>   $dpi_x   = 150;
>   $dpi_y   = 150;
>  
>   // Read the file
>   $size    = filesize($file);
>   $image   = file_get_contents($file);
>
>   // Update DPI information in the JPG header
>   $image[13] = chr(1);
>   $image[14] = chr(floor($dpi_x/256));
>   $image[15] = chr(      $dpi_x%256);
>   $image[16] = chr(floor($dpi_y/256));
>   $image[17] = chr(      $dpi_y%256);
>
>   // Write the new JPG
>   $f = fopen($file, 'w');
>   fwrite($f, $msg, $size);
>   fclose($f);
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: so what is then the param for quality, if not dpi ?

Comment: @provance — See the third paragraph of this answer.

Comment: and is that  - `imageresolution` - what is changed by third param of `imagejpg()` ?

Comment: No. `imgresolution` changes the DPI metadata, like I said, and like you asked for. The third argument to `imagejpg` changes the quality, like you said.

Comment: please excuse me. What is called tha param for quality - if not `dpi` - and if not `imageresolution` ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask now. Quality and DPI are different things. `imageresolution` is a function where you can specify the DPI as an argument. `imagejpeg` is a function where you can specify the quality as an argument. They are different functions. They take different arguments. They do different things.

Comment: quality is number of pixels per inch isn't it ? And it is called resolution, isn't it ?

Comment: "quality is number of pixels per inch isn't it ?" — **NO**. See the first sentence of this answer, and the third paragraph of this answer.

Comment: you say - `The quality determines how much compression to use`. Compression what ? Compression of space between pixels? Keeping the number of pixels untouched ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression